# Using If and else statements to determine whether user inputted number is in range. C#

Tags: c#

I'm writing a program in C# that prompts the user to enter a number for one of the months in a year. Once they enter a number, it supposed to reply with either an error message stating it's invalid or a message saying the number is valid. Right now it prompts the user correctly, but it doesn't spit out the messages that I want it to, it just ends. Here is the code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MonthChecky
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const int LowNum = 1;
            const int HighNum = 12;

            Console.Write("Please enter a valid number for a month: ");
            String UserIn = Console.ReadLine();


            if (Convert.ToInt32(UserIn) < LowNum)
                if (Convert.ToInt32(UserIn) > HighNum)

            Console.WriteLine("That is an invalid number, try entering a number between 1 and 12");

            else
                Console.WriteLine("That is a valid number for a month");
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just how can a number be both < LowNum and > HighNum?  What if they enter 'enter'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is completely incorrect. Here is your code properly bracketed:

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(UserIn) < LowNum) {
    if (Convert.ToInt32(UserIn) > HighNum) {
        Console.WriteLine("That is an invalid number, try entering a number between 1 and 12");
    } else {
        Console.WriteLine("That is a valid number for a month");
    }
} // No "else"
```

This code would print *anything* only if the number entered is below 1. Moreover, it would never print `"That is an invalid number"`, because the number must be above 12 *and* below 1 at the same time, which is impossible.

You need to change your code to use `&&` to evaluate both conditions at once. Use `int.TryParse` to check the validity of user input.

```
int n;
if (int.TryParse(UserIn, out n) && n >= LowNum && n <= HighNum) {
    Console.WriteLine("That is a valid number for a month");
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("That is an invalid number, try entering a number between 1 and 12");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As was noted in the comments you're going to want to use

```
Int.Parse(input);
```

to verify that they've input a number, instead of Convert.ToInt32(input) as this will throw if it's not a number.

Finally, add a

```
Console.ReadLine();
```

at the end to prevent the program from just closing

So:

```
var userIn = Console.Readline();
var number = 0;
if (!Int.TryParse(userIn, out number)){
    Exit;
}

if (number < LowNum || number > highNum)
{
    Console.WriteLine("That is an invalid number, try entering a number between 1 and 12");
}
else 
{
    Console.WriteLine("That is a valid number for a month");
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: The Console.ReadLine at the end is a bad idea. Now if I run the program from the command prompt I will always unnecessarily need to press Enter to exit the program although it has finished. Console programs normally don’t behave that way - just look at any console program like netsh, tracert and so on. If you don’t want that the console window closes when started from the IDE just start it with Ctrl+F5.

Answer (score 0):

`Or` boolean operator to fix and simplify the if statement, `ReadLine` call to not automatically close the console window, and `int.Parse` usage.

```
if (int.Parse(UserIn) < LowNum || int.Parse(UserIn) > HighNum) // "or" operator
    Console.WriteLine("That is an invalid number, try entering a number between 1 and 12");
else
    Console.WriteLine("That is a valid number for a month");

Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Logic of the code is very poor. You simply want to check your input numbers are within the specified rang. Your code never check for valid rang.

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(UserIn) < LowNum)
    if (Convert.ToInt32(UserIn) > HighNum)

        Console.WriteLine("That is an invalid number, try entering a number between 1 and 12");

        else
            Console.WriteLine("That is a valid number for a month");
```

So, it should be like this:

```
if ((Convert.ToInt32(UserIn) < LowNum || (Convert.ToInt32(UserIn) > HighNum)
{
    Console.WriteLine("That is an invalid number, try entering a number between 1 and 12");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("That is a valid number for a month");
}

Console.ReadLine()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether the input is a non negative digit as well as its an integer(not string ,bool) .

```
  int intValue;
            bool inputSuccess = int.TryParse(UserIn, out intValue);
             if(inputSuccess)
                 {
                     if (intValue > HighNum)
                      {
                   Console.WriteLine("That is an invalid number, try entering a number between 1 and 12");
                      } 
                 else if(intValue<LowNum )
                       {
                        Console.WriteLine("That is an invalid number, try entering a number between 1 and 12");
                       }
                        else
                      {
                           Console.WriteLine("That is a valid number for a month");
                      }
                 }
            else
               {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter digits");
              }
```